# I am getting 'TypeError: dispatch is not a function' inside of my aler.js action file whenever I try to run the action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

> I am new to using Redux. I have made a reducer and action to have an alert display whenever an item is saved. However, when I try to save that item, I get the following error
> [TypeError: dispatch is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnpQD.png)

> I haven't had much luck finding how dispatch is supposed to be passed through the action...

> **alert.js (Action):**

```
import { REMOVE_ALERT, SET_ALERT } from './types';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

// Action to dispatch the type to the reducer (adds alert to the state)
export const setAlert = (msg, alertType) => (dispatch) => {
  const id = uuid();
  dispatch({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: { msg, alertType, id },
  });
  setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: id }), 3000);
};
```

> **This is where I am trying to call setAlert() action (Inside the SaveButton Component):**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setAlert } from '../../actions/alert';
import TurnedInNotOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/TurnedInNotOutlined';

const SaveButton = (props) => {
  const { handleClick } = props;
  return (
    <div className='saveBtn'>
      <button
        className='btn'
        onClick={(handleClick, setAlert('Tweet Saved! '))}
      >
        <TurnedInNotOutlinedIcon />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

SaveButton.propTypes = {
  setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, { setAlert })(SaveButton);
```

> **This is the reducer (alert.js):**

```
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from '../actions/types';

// Initial State
const initialState = [];

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_ALERT:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case REMOVE_ALERT:
      return state.filter((alert) => alert.id !== action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

> Sorry for the code overload, I wanted to make sure I included everything.

Comment: Are you using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#installation) middleware?

Comment: @MattCarlotta I believe I am, but I am not 100% sure.
I imported 'redux-thunk' inside of my store.js file

```import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()) ||
      compose
  )
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Hard to say what's wrong without a working example. If you have a repo to share, I can take a look. Otherwise, I'd recommend replicating the problem as a very stripped down version of your code (just the code needed to replicate the problem!!!) into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new). If you get this stripped down version working, then you should be able to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: My guess is that if it's not related to thunk, then it's related to how you're calling it: ```onClick={(handleClick, setAlert('Tweet Saved! '))}```. I'm not sure why you're passing onClick two functions. Instead it should contain a single callback function: ```onClick={handleClick}``` or ```onClick={(e) => { handleClick(e); setAlert(...); }}```.